# Ribbon черное окно

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017, fluent-ribbon

Не понимаю. В VS-2017 пытаюсь сделать ribbonWindow, но окно получается черным. Открываю старые проекты, в которых есть RibbonWindow созданные в VS2013, такой проблемы нет.

[image: Вид окна]

Сам FluentRibbon ставился через NuGet, никаких настроек дополнительно не делал.

Описание окна:

```
<r:RibbonWindow x:Class="test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:r="urn:fluent-ribbon"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <r:Ribbon>
            <r:RibbonTabItem Header="Main">
                <r:RibbonGroupBox Header="Grop">
                    <r:Button Header="Button"></r:Button>
                </r:RibbonGroupBox>
            </r:RibbonTabItem>
        </r:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</r:RibbonWindow>
```

App.Xaml

```
<Application x:Class="test.App"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: А если установить `Background="White"`?

Comment: Нужно тему установить в `App.xaml`, посмотрите в документации - http://fluentribbon.github.io/documentation/basic-setup

Comment: @FoggyFinder, Спасибо. Именно в этом дело оказалось. Со временем забылось :-) Может еще подскажите, у меня в режиме конструктора, ни в одном из проектов не отрисовываются картинки назначенные на элементы ribbon. Просто пустые квадраты. Так и задуманно или только у меня такая проблема?

Comment: не знаю, не пользовался риббон, есть возможность сделать демо и выложить на гитхаб?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, на гидхаб врят ли :-) Но демку с одной кнопкой могу сделать.

Comment: давайте тогда так =)

Comment: @FoggyFinder ну попробовал сформулировать в новой теме. Там же ссылка на github на демку приложения https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/764177/fluent-ribbon-%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%83%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно еще добавить указание на словарь ресурсов

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Attach default Theme -->
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

тогда элемент управления сможет поменять свой стиль в соответствии с указанной темой.