# Fluent-Ribbon: Отсутствуют картинки на контроллах в режиме конструктора

Tags: c#, wpf, fluent-ribbon

Перешел на новый риббон. Прикрепляю картинки на элементы интерфейса, но они отображаются только в запущенном приложении. В режиме дизайнера они не отображаются.

[image: Окно в режиме конструктора]

[image: Окно в режиме запущенного приложения]

Не понимаю, то ли студия не настроена, то ли в коде у меня ошибка и дизайнер не понимает откуда ему брать картинки.

В принципе все делал как и всегда:

*App.xaml:*

```
<Application x:Class="ribbonimages.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;Component/Themes/Generic.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

*MainWindow.xaml:*

```
<r:RibbonWindow x:Class="ribbonimages.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:r="urn:fluent-ribbon"
        Title="Test View Images in Ribbon Constructor" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <r:Ribbon>
            <r:RibbonTabItem Header="Закладочка">
                <r:RibbonGroupBox Header="Группочка">
                    <r:Button Header="Новый" LargeIcon="\Images\New.png"></r:Button>
                    <r:Button Header="Открыть" LargeIcon="\Images\Open.png"></r:Button>
                    <r:Button Header="Сохранить" LargeIcon="\Images\Save.png"></r:Button>
                </r:RibbonGroupBox>
            </r:RibbonTabItem>
        </r:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</r:RibbonWindow>
```

Полный код примера выложил на [github](https://github.com/pincher1519/RibbonImages.git)
Код написан на VS-2013, но такая же ситуация и на vs-2017.

Заранее спасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте указать полный URI

```
<r:Button Header="Новый" LargeIcon="pack://application:,,,/ribbonimages;component/Images/New.png" />
<r:Button Header="Открыть" LargeIcon="pack://application:,,,/ribbonimages;component/Images/Open.png" />
<r:Button Header="Сохранить" LargeIcon="pack://application:,,,/ribbonimages;component/Images/Save.png" />
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вы снова мне помогли 

Comment: @pincher1519 У меня та же проблема, только в имени проекта закрался пробел. И теперь вариант, который вы предложили ругается, что не может найти данный ресурс. Можно как-то исправить это? Переименование проекта пока не представляется возможным